# Doesn't the standard object initialization in Objective-C lead to memory leaks?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

The standard way to create an object in Objective-C looks like this:

```
MyClass* object = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

The standard implementation of *MyClass*'s *init* method would look something like this:

```
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) { /* initialize */ }
    return self;
}
```

Aside from some syntax changes, and excluding factory methods, that seems to be the recommended way to write an init method, and to use it.

As I understand it, the purpose of *self = [super init];* is to handle the case where *[super init]* fails.  But if it does fail, and returns nil, wouldn't there be a memory leak?  The reason being that *MyClass*'s init will return nil, *object* will be nil, there will be no more pointers that reference the object allocated with *[MyClass alloc]*, and therefore no way to release it.

These are the two solutions I can think of are, but I haven't seen either one in regular practice.

After a call to *alloc*, check the results before calling init:

```
MyClass* object = [MyClass alloc];
if(object == nil) { /*handle the error */ }
else { object = [object init]; }
```

Or, if *[super init]* fails, release the memory.  Something like this:

```
-(id) init
{
    id temp = [super init];
    if(!temp) { [self release]; }
    self = temp;
    if(self) { /* initialize */ }
    return self;
}
```

Am I wrong in that reasoning?  It could be argued that *[super init]* is unlikely to fail, but then why assign the results of it to *self* and check for nil?  I'd be happy to see some clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `[super init]` wants to return nil, it should also call `release` on self.

Answer (score 2):

An `init` method should get rid of the object if it decides to abort and return `nil`.

However, that's just what the `if (self)` covers. The `self = [super init]` serves another purpose: An `init` method is allowed to return something other than the object that the message was sent to. For a real-life example, `[NSArray alloc]` returns a dummy object, and that object's various `init…` methods return the real array.