# Returning nil in the init in Objective C code

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In the case, if we return nil in the init method, what's happening with retain count and who is going to release this object?

As I undertand as soon as we called alloc (which will happen before init), the retain count will become 1. Now, init is called and let say for some reason it can't initialize the object, so it returns nil.

And it looks like now we have the object with retain count equal 1 and nobody has reference to it to call release.

Should we call [self autorelease] in init for such case or do something else?

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083654/doesnt-the-standard-object-initialization-in-objective-c-lead-to-memory-leaks

Answer (score 47, accepted):

See [Allocating and Initializing Objects](https://web.archive.org/web/20101206080325mp_/http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW13) in the documentation.

Specifically, if you have an error in your initializer, then you `release` `self` and return `nil`:

```
- init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
         if (... failed to initialize something in self ...) {
             [self release];
             return nil;
         }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now, consider what happens when you call `[super init]` and it returns `nil`.   The above pattern has already been employed, what was `self` has been released, and the `nil` return indicates that the instance is gone.   There is no leak and everyone is happy.

This is also a valid pattern (assume that `self` is an instance of `MyClass`):

```
- init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        ... normal initialization here ...
    } else {
        self = [MyClass genericInstanceWhenInitializationGoesBad];
        self = [self retain];
    }
    return self;
 }
```

Since `init` is expected to return something that is `retained` (by implication of being chained from `+alloc`), then that `[self retain]`, though it looks goofy, is actually correct.   The `self = [self retain]` is just being extra defensive in case `MyClass` overrides `retain` to do something weird.

Comment: Thank you. Got it. I missed that somehow in the documentation, that I need to release self before return nil.

Comment: Try this link halfway down the page: 'Handling Initialization Failure'  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-105377

Comment: Yup.  Thanks... SO really needs compiler and runtime integration.

Comment: what about in ARC, does it know to `[self release]`, or should I set self to nil?

Comment: Link does not exist any more, closest I can find is https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW54, got anything better?

Comment: @bbum what is the point of assigning `self` to `nil` if all we do after it is return? Just to be safe in case of future changes in `init...`?

Comment: Lack of ambiguity?  Tradition, really.

Answer (score -5):

Usually, you will call

```
self = [super init];
if (self == nil) {

   return nil;
}
// do some init job here
return self;
```

It is not your job to autorelease the self, because when you have it, it is already nil,so even if you call `[self autorelease];`, it does nothing.

I think the NSObject init method has to deal with the object already

Comment: why not 
`if(self) {
    // do some init job here
}

return self` 
?