# iOS Completion Block Returning (null)

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, class-method

I am running a class method that has a completion block with an object that I want to return. However, when I get the value back, the properties are all there but the debugger says that object is (null) despite having a memory address when looking at more details. Does anyone know how this can be possible. Thanks!!

I have also attached an image to my debug area where the (null) is shown

http://cl.ly/image/1d2j0z1D0u1p

```
+ (void)getBoard:(NSInteger)boardId withUser:(User *)user completion:(void (^)(Board *board))compBoard {
    NSDictionary* headers = @{@"Accept": @"application/json", @"Authorization": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", user._token]};
    [[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
        [request setUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/boards/%zd", REST_URL, boardId]];
        [request setHeaders:headers];
    }] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse *jsonResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonResponse rawBody] options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Response status of boards: %ld\n%@", (long) jsonResponse.code, json);
        if ( jsonResponse.code >= 200 && jsonResponse.code <= 300 ) {
            NSDictionary *boardDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonResponse rawBody] options:kNilOptions error:&error];

            Board *board = [[Board alloc] init];

            board._courseId = [[boardDict objectForKey:@"courseId"] integerValue];
            board._udid = [[boardDict objectForKey:@"boardId"] integerValue];
            board._boardName = [boardDict objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSDate *dateModified = [NSDate convertFromStringFromRemote:[boardDict objectForKey:@"lastModified"]];
            board._dateModified = dateModified;
            NSDate *dateCreated = [NSDate convertFromStringFromRemote:[boardDict objectForKey:@"createdDate"]];
            board._dateCreated = dateCreated;

            compBoard(board);
        }
    }];
}
```

Place I am calling it

```
- (void)addBoardWithNotification:(NSNumber *)entityId {
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    [CourseViewModal getBoard:[entityId integerValue] withUser:weakSelf._currentUser completion:^(Board *board) {
    Course *boardCourse = [weakSelf._currentUser getCourseForId:board._courseId];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if ( ![boardCourse doesBoardNameExist:board._boardName] ) {
                [boardCourse._boards addObject:board];
                [self._currentUser addBoard:board toCourseId:boardCourse._udid];

                NSNotification *addBoardNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:AddBoardNotificationString object:self userInfo:@{@"BoardObject" : board}];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:addBoardNotification];
            }
        });
    }];
}
```

Comment: can you check if it's passing through if statement that checks .code length

Comment: Does Board have a `description` method that is returning nil, perchance?

Comment: bbum: Unfortunately, no description method

Comment: what do you mean by .code length?

Answer (score 0):

I tried code flow you are using, could not see any issue from block setup you are using -- looks like you have some other part of the code which is creating issue.

Test code - with no issue

```
+(void) get:(myCompletion) compblock asJsonAsync:(myCompletion) compblock2{
    //do stuff

    compblock(nil);

    NSDictionary *ret2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"compblock2"] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Key"]];
    compblock2(ret2);
}
+(void) myMethod:(myCompletion) compblock {
    //do stuff

    [ViewController get:^(NSDictionary* finished) {
        if(finished){
            NSLog(@"compblock %@",[finished objectForKey:@"Key"]);
        }

        compblock(finished);



    } asJsonAsync:^(NSDictionary* finished) {
        if(finished){
            NSLog(@"compblock2 %@",[finished objectForKey:@"Key"]);
        }

        NSDictionary *ret = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"compblock2"] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Key"]];

        compblock(ret);

    }];

}


//call
    [ViewController myMethod:^(NSDictionary* finished) {
        if(finished){
            NSLog(@"success %@",[finished objectForKey:@"Key"]);
        }else {
            NSLog(@"nil");
        }
    }];
```

Can you check following code works

```
+ (void)getBoard:(NSInteger)boardId withUser:(User *)user completion:(void (^)(Board *board))compBoard {
    NSDictionary* headers = @{@"Accept": @"application/json", @"Authorization": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", user._token]};
    [[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
        [request setUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/boards/%zd", REST_URL, boardId]];
        [request setHeaders:headers];
    }] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse *jsonResponse, NSError *error) {
           Board *board = [[Board alloc] init];
           compBoard(board);
    }];
}
```

Comment: I edited my question to show the only place I am calling the method. Seems to return (null) immediately

Comment: Can you try getBoard sample code I have placed to test.

Comment: Tested it. same result :/ what is weird is that the board is (null) even right after allocating it. I have plenty of other Board objects that behave fine so it has to be something isolated in this block

Comment: Issue could be related to your request response - try with some simple (http://www.google.com) URL - check Board can be created in the block.

Comment: Check one more init function of Board class is get called - if called make sure issue is not similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336953/returning-nil-in-the-init-in-objective-c-code